# Datepicker for Bootstrap on mobile devices changing Format

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, datepicker, format, input-field

I'm using following datepicker: (http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/) for my date-Field.

`<input class="datepicker" style="width:100px;border-radius: 4px;" type="text" placeholder="Datum" id="startDate"....`

I'm using two diffrent formats 'dd.mm.yyyy' and 'mm/dd/yyyy' and everthing is fine.
But on mobile devices the keyboard opens when I tap in the input-field.

Because of this I used the native datepicker with `<input type='date'....` but this one does not support different formats.

Is there anyway to disable the keyboard on a `input type=text` element?

Or do you know any other datepicker with different formats?

Thx for your help

Comment: Found a solution: just added the attribute `readonly='true'` to the input

Answer (score 0):

Try this: If you add onfocus="blur();" to the element this will not let soft keyboards to open. Therefore you will not get keyboard open on mobile devices.

```js
$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-datepicker@1.9.0/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-datepicker@1.9.0/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="sandbox-container"><input type="text" class="form-control" onfocus="blur();"></div>
```